# PUT API call is deleting record instead of updating

Tags: vba, rest, restful-url

I am trying to update data in API using PUT request, but instead its deleting that particular row.
I see some forum to include saving option but where am i supposed to do it. if i do requesturl/save then i get error of "method not value"

my code

```
Try

    Dim myRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(requestURL), HttpWebRequest)

    With myRequest

        .Method = "PUT"
        .ContentType = "application/json"
        .Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & authHeaderString)


    End With

    

    Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(myRequest.GetRequestStream())
        streamWriter.Write(jsonobj)
        ' streamWriter.Close()
    End Using

    Return myRequest

Catch ex As Exception

    sMessage = ex.Message
    Return Nothing
End Try
```

Comment: Please share the code you have so far as well as the API you're using.

Comment: "https://api.timetap.com/test/schedulerField". This is the api i am using . to be precise requesturl